# Multi-site customization

Tags: customization, multisite, javascript

Can a multi-site be customized as such so that it is running in the backend and you can link all sites to frontend via some interface (javascript alike I assume)?

Comment: Maybe just me but I do not understand the question.  Maybe you can expand on it a bit, or give an example of what your desired outcome is and what options you've already researched/considered?

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a site in the frontend so that its design and usability (UI and UX) are independent of its backend sites.  Please have a look at this image which hopefully can clarify what I mean: http://prnt.sc/dt8guq

Comment: The JS frontend is doable, though I am not sure how that can be beneficial.
While a JS powered combined admin interface is also possible, I don't think the stress will be worth is

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to have the frontend to be independent of backend WordPress from design and security perspectives as well as future addons.